# save dygraph chart into jpg image on my local hard drive

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

I am working with JavasSript Dygraphs chart. Everything is fine but what i need to do is to be able to save it on my local hard drive as an image. Below is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var img;
  g3 = new Dygraph(
   img = document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
    "temperatures.csv",
    {
       rollPeriod: 9,
       showRoller: true,  
    }
    );
</script>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <div>
     <div id='graphdiv3'></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a hidden image element in your page and export the image to the users disk but the issue is the downloaded file will not have any filetype. The user can open the downloaded file in any image viewer.

```
var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
Dygraph.Export.asPNG(graph, img);
window.location.href = img.src.replace('image/png','image/octet-stream');
```

This uses the dygraph-export library from this link http://cavorite.com/labs/js/dygraphs-export/

Answer (score 2):

There's no official way to do this, but a dygraphs user has done some work along these lines:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dygraphs-users/whcMjtBE7s0/discussion